# Question about multivariable functions and their derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

[The problems in question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQkHr.jpg)

I've received these three problems to solve, but frankly, I have no idea how to start. Can someone explain how to do question b and c?

Comment: b is asking you to find f(t,at) I believe. And then to find the derivative of that with respect to t.

Comment: If you have no idea where to start, you should begin by reviewing your notes on partial differentiation, and the directional derivative. These are very broad topics, but if there is a specific point where you're stuck, maybe we can help.

Comment: At question b, I'd like to know how to find out if the composite function is differentiable, and at question c, I'd like to know how I can reconsile my answer with my answer in part b and the chain rule.

Comment: You should type in your question or at least import it into MSE. The URL of that image may not work in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $r(t)=(t,at)$ , so $x(t) = t , y(t) = at$.

If you want to know what $f \circ r$ is, you need to substitute $x(t) , y(t)$ into $f(x,y)$.

for $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ you can write:

$$f(x(t),y(t)) = \frac{x^2 y}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{t^2\cdot (at)}{t^2 + (at)^2}=\frac{at^3}{(a^2+1)t^2}=\frac{a}{a^2+1} t$$

This is true for $t\neq 0$, but at $t=0$ , $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and the function becomes

$$ (f\circ r) (0) = f(0,0) = 0 $$

So in conclusion,

$$(f\circ r) (t) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{a}{a^2+1} t , t\neq 0\\ 
0 , t=0
\end{matrix}\right.$$

This can be written as $ (f \circ r) (t) = \frac{a}{a^2+1} t $, and the derivative of that function at $t=0$ is easy:

$$\frac{d}{dt} (f\circ r) |_{t=0} = \frac{a}{a^2+1} $$

---

Now for c:
We need to calculate Df at $(0,0)$. Since $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} $ , we conclude that $Df$ is a matrix with dimensions $1 \times 2$ , a row vector:

$$ Df = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} , \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} )$$

Now, to calculate the partial derivatives, we'll use their definitions:

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (0,0) = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{f(0+\Delta x, 0 ) - f(0,0)}{\Delta x} = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{f(\Delta x, 0 ) - f(0,0)}{\Delta x}  = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{\frac{(\Delta x)^2 \cdot 0}{(\Delta x)^2 + 0^2}-0}{\Delta x} = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{0-0}{\Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{0}{\Delta x} = 0$$

And doing the same calculation for y, we get

$$ Df = (0,0) $$
meaning that $Df(0,0) \cdot r'(0) = (0,0)\cdot r'(0) = 0 \neq \frac{a}{a^2+1} = (f \circ r)'(0)$
Meaning the chain law (c) and the direct calculation (b) don't agree with each other. How come?

The answer is the function isn't differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Again, will see that with the definition of differentaible. If the function was differentiable then:

$$ \lim_{||(\Delta x , \Delta y)|| \to 0} \frac{f(\Delta x , \Delta y) - f(0,0) - Df \cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
\Delta x\\ 
\Delta y
\end{pmatrix}
}{||(\Delta x , \Delta y)||} = 0 $$

But $$ Df = (0,0) , f(0,0)=0 $$
and so we get the following limit:

$$ \lim_{||(\Delta x , \Delta y)|| \to 0} \frac{f(\Delta x , \Delta y)
}{||(\Delta x , \Delta y)||} = \lim_{||(\Delta x , \Delta y)|| \to 0} \frac{\frac{(\Delta x)^2 (\Delta y)}{(\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2}
}{||(\Delta x , \Delta y)||} =\lim_{||(\Delta x , \Delta y)|| \to 0} \frac{(\Delta x)^2 (\Delta y)}{((\Delta x)^2 + (\Delta y)^2)^{\frac32}}
 $$

And by substituting $\Delta y = a \Delta x $ you get something that is $a$ dependent and not $0$  - meaning the limit does not converge to $0$ and the function isn't differentiable, thus making the chain law not appliable.

QED

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I totally get it now.